# What card game is this? Similar to spades

Tags: spades, all-fours

I'm from a latin american country and a game called casino is very popular (not to be confused with poker or actually casino games)
It's a four player game with a partnership. Making it a 2v2. The first team to reach 21 points wins. 
The cards considered points are the aces scoring as 1 point. The 10 of diamonds and the 2 of spades both counting as 2 points respectively.

The dealer gives 13 cards to each player.
This is where the games separates itself from spades or all fours.
Instead of going by rounds and winning tricks or bidding how many points you'll get, the game is played by taking towards your team as many cards as possible. You do this by taking same numbered cards.

Example. The first player to play puts down a 4 (since it's advice to start playing low numbered cards) the next player decides, if possible, to take the 4 in the table with a 4 of his own. If he does he adds to the team card pool. If he wishes not to take the card or can't he has to drop another card. For example putting down a 3.
Now the next player may choose to use a 7 he has in his hand and take both cards, (because 4+3=7) and so on and so forth.

Points start appearing when you add them to a certain card. For example if you know you have all four kings you can add an ace (which counts as a number 1) to a queen (making it 13 the numerical value of a king)

At the end of the round you count how many aces your team got or if you got the 10 of diamonds or the 2 of spades
So that's the main difference with other trick and bid games. There are times where there are several cards in th table when the first 4 turns finish and players may choose to either take or add and combine cards.

Comment: You've already identified the game as Casino. If that's not the game, could you clarify in what way it differs or why that is not the answer to your question in your question?

Comment: This isn't even a question - you've just written a short description of a game you already know the identity for.

Comment: Judging by the answer, it would seem the extra S in the name is throwing off his search. Searching for "casino card game" or something is almost never going to yield the result he's looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. I had tried googling casino card game many times before yet every single result was poker or some other las Vegas type gambling game. Never occurred to me to Google it with 2 s. Anyway I'm happy you were all helpful.

Comment: Funny cause I googled 'Casino card game' and got the Wikipedia page for Cassino as the third entry and the other two were rules for 'Casino' which looked similar to your rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [Cassino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassino_(card_game)) (also called Casino according to Wikipedia).

Comment: Thanks for the help. That tricky second s was throwing off my searches. I'm glad my country didn't swap the original name or else it would've been so much harder to find the game. Thanks

Comment: You should edit more details about the game into the answer, so that it's clearer to others how/why it matches the asker's description.